# Function that returns the length of the maximum sub-array with condition

Tags: python, algorithm

An array of zeros and ones is given to the input. A function has to be implemented that returns the length of the maximum subsequence in which the number of zeros and ones matches. Example of a sequence: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]. In an array slice from 1 (indexing from 0) to 8, the number of zeros is equal to the number of ones and the length of the subarray is 8.
Below is a code that solves the task partially, solves most tests, but not all of them

```
def longest_subsequence(arr):
    hash_table = {}
    k = 0
    max_ = 0
    temp = None
    for idx, el in enumerate(arr):
        if el == 0:
            k += 1
        else:
            k -= 1

        if k not in hash_table:
            hash_table[k] = idx

        if k in hash_table:
            temp = idx - hash_table[k]

        if temp > max_:
            max_ = temp

    return max_
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def longest_subsequence(arr):
    hash_table = {0:-1}
    k = 0
    max_ = 0
    temp = None
    for idx, el in enumerate(arr):
        if el == 0:
            k += 1
        else:
            k -= 1

        if k not in hash_table:
            hash_table[k] = idx

        if k in hash_table:
            temp = idx - hash_table[k]

        if temp > max_:
            max_ = temp

    return max_
```